# connectedness in terms of open partitions of spaces

Tags: general-topology

A space is usually defined to be connected if it can't be nontrivially partitioned into opens.

Can we relax the word 'opens' to 'spaces' and equality to homeomorphism?

In other words, is the following true:

A space is disconnected iff it is isomorphic to the topological disjoint union of two nonempty spaces.

How to see this?

Comment: what topology do you put on the union of the two spaces?

Comment: @M.Van the sum topology, which is the final topology w.r.t. the canonical embeddings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the same, because in a disjoint sum of two spaces, both these (copies of) spaces are open in the whole sum.

So, formally, if $X$ is homeomorphic (not isomorphic!) to $A \oplus B$, where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty spaces, there exists a homeomorphism $h: X \rightarrow S = (A \times \{0\}) \cup (B \times \{1\})$, where the latter set has the finest topology that makes both $i_A: A \rightarrow S$ and $i_B: B \rightarrow S$ continuous, with $i_A(a) = (a,0), i_B(b) = (b,1)$. This means that $O \subseteq S$ is open iff $(i_A)^{-1}[O]$ is open in $A$ and $(i_B)^{-1}[O]$ is open in $B$.

Then $A \times \{0\}$ is open in $S$ because $(i_A)^{-1}[A \times \{0\}] = A$ and $(i_B)^{-1}[A \times \{0\}] = \emptyset$. Similarly $B \times \{1\}$ is open in $S$ as well. It follows that, because $h$ is continuous and surjective that $h^{-1}[A \times \{0\}]$ and $h^{-1}[B \times \{1\}]$ form a disjoint non-trivial partition of $X$.

On the other hand, if $X = U \cup V$ where $U,V$ are non-empty open, and disjoint, a subset $O$ in $X$ is open iff $O \cap U$ and $O \cap V$ are both open in their respective subspace topologies. This is easy to check. But then $X$ is homeomorphic to $U \oplus V$ (in their subspace topology).

Comment: Why do you write "not isomorphic"? Homeomorphism is the isomorphism of topological spaces, no?

Comment: @popo In topology one uses homeomorphism (which is a special type of isomorphism if you view categorically). Isomorphisms often preserve some extra structure (e.g. in topological groups we need to distinguish them), so topologists avoid isomorphism as a term in purely topology context.

Comment: Okay, but is there any harm if we work in the category of topological spaces alone? Isos in this category are precisely homeomorphisms, no?

Comment: @popo In that case you could do it, but I would state it explicitly. It could be confusing. If I read isomorphism of spaces, I immediately think "as what"?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma it seems that the heart of the matter is that pullback along $h$ preserves partitions. In this case, I think this happens because coproducts in the category of spaces are disjoint, which lets us use the fact $h^\ast$ commutes with unions and intersection (preserves disjointness). I am wondering, then, if this characterization gives a good notion of connectedness in a category with coproducts which are disjoint and universal.

Comment: @Arrow there are other categorical notions of connectedness (defined by Herrlich, I think; that's where I've seen them). One could also use the special space $D_2 = \{0,1\}$ in the discrete topology: a space is disconnected iff it has a continuous surjective map (so epimorpism in this case) to $D_2$.